# How to add new issue to a milestone in github?

Tags: github, project

In my private github repository, I've created a new milestone. I want to add new issues to it.

[image]

I click on New issue button but it redirects to the following page:
[image]

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, check if using the [GitHub CLI `gh`](https://cli.github.com/manual/) would help.

From [Creating an issue with GitHub CLI](https://docs.github.com/en/issues/tracking-your-work-with-issues/creating-an-issue#creating-an-issue-with-github-cli):

> To create an issue, use the [`gh issue create`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_issue_create) subcommand.
> To skip the interactive prompts, include the `--body` and the `--title` flags.
>
> ```
> gh issue create --title "My new issue" --body "Here are more details."
> ```
>
> You can also specify assignees, labels, milestones, and projects.
>
> ```
> gh issue create --title "My new issue" --body "Here are more details." \
>                 --assignee @me,monalisa --label "bug,help wanted" \
>                 --project onboarding --milestone "learning codebase"
> ```